# Adding JobId to Resque logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, resque

As the question title implies, I am trying to add the id of the resque job to the logs.  In my regular rails logging I have setup tagged logging, so every log entry has the context of the request.  I'm not sure how to do that for resque jobs - is the job id available in the context of the logs?

Basically I want to do something like this:

```
Resque.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Logger.new(STDOUT))
Resque.log_tags = [
  proc do |job|
    job["id"]
  end
]
```

This is psuedo code, it obviously doesn't work.

The closest thing I have found is [this](https://github.com/jeremy/resque-rails-tagged-logger) gem, which still doesn't do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `resque` source code, i found that currently there is no way you can do this. But, you can use money patching to achieve your desire goal. You can do something like

```
module Resque::Logging
  def self.log(severity, message)
   log_message = "[#{::Process.pid}]  #{message}" 
   Resque.logger.__send__(severity, log_message) if Resque.logger
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think you quite read the question.  Process.pid != job.id

Comment: isnt `Process.pid` is unique in all worker processes ? There is nothing like `job id` in `resque`. there is one extension of resque which does provide job id but it is simply generating random unique id https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status/blob/master/lib/resque/plugins/status/hash.rb#L168 . FYI, in sidekiq, the logs are tagged with `process id` .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gem 'resque-status' which generates a job_id for each job.

The only problem is that you will need to change all the calls to Resque.enqueue for something like:

job_id = ExampleJob.create(:parameter => 'something')

Resque-Status --> https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status